# Hamburger menu z-index issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I made a hamburger menu for the mobile responsive mode of my website and the menu works but because it's layered above all other components I am not able to click on buttons or select anything, this happens even when the hamburger menu is closed. Is it possible to change the z-index only when the hamburger menu is open?

**Navbar component**

The problem is with the `nav-menu` div

```
function Topbar() {
  const timeout = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
        uncheckAll();
      }
    }, 600);
  };

  function check(checked = true) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.checkbox');
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
      checkbox.checked = checked;
    });
  }

  function uncheckAll() {
    check(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="menu">
          <div className="label">Navbar</div>
          <div className="spacer"></div>
          <div className="item">
            <span>
              <a href="#Intro" className="link">
                HOME
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span>
              <a href="#About" className="link">
                About
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span>
              <a href="#Projects" className="link">
                PROJECTS
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span>
              <a href="#Contact" className="link">
                CONTACT
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nav-menu">
        <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" />
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <ul id="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#Intro" className="link" onClick={timeout}>
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#About" className="link" onClick={timeout}>
                About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Projects" className="link" onClick={timeout}>
                Projects
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Contact" className="link" onClick={timeout}>
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Topbar;
```

**SASS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 619px) {
  .nav .navbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav .nav-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav .nav-menu #menuToggle {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -moz-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -o-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menuToggle {
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  display: none;
  min-width: 85%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  animation: moveRight ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 45px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.315);
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: flex;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: flex;
  width: 29px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 10000;
  transform-origin: 5px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
    opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-3px, -1px);
  background: white;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 7px;
  width: 85%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(56, 56, 56);
  height: 100%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.989);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hamburger-menu-w456br?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: can you reproduce a working enviornment like sandbox or any thing

Comment: Yes, I have update the question with link to CodeSandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some pointer-event css property can fix this....

[here is the solution.... see it and ask if u need help](https://codesandbox.io/s/hamburger-menu-forked-mselfl)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was this easy